# Raycast to get gameobject being hit to run script and function on gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, raycasting

I'm in the process of getting multiple enemies to work in my game for my college project. I have a player with a ShootGun script which raycasts the gun and detects whether or not the object hit is one of the enemy colliders (tagged with Enemy_Head, _Torso and _Limb). If it is, it will get the gameobject of the enemy hit and the enemyHealth script component on that gameobject and will then call public functions on that script. Currently, when the ShootGun script tries to get the component / script it says the following error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ShootGun.gunFire () (at Assets/Scripts/Gun/ShootGun.cs:107)

**UPDATED ERROR CODE:**

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ShootGun.gunFire () (at Assets/Scripts/Gun/ShootGun.cs:113)

Line 113 = enHit.enemyShotTorso();

The error appears for each line where enHit tries to call a function from the enemyHealth script.

The following is the raycast within my ShootGun script:

```
// Raycasting for bullet projection against obstacles within the world (WIP)
            float gunRayDistance = 50f;

            Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera>().ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 0));

            // Name what for the raycast collides with (used to reference the target point)
            RaycastHit hit;

            // The actual raycast
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, gunRayDistance, 1 << 9) || Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, gunRayDistance, 1 << 8)) {
                Debug.Log("Bullet Hit");

                EnemyHealth enHit = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();

                // Checking if the raycast (bullet) collided with objects tagged with "Enemy_Head".
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy_Head")) {
                    Debug.Log ("Headshot!");
                    //hitPoint = hit.collider.gameObject;
                    enHit = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
                    enHit.enemyShotHead();
                }
                // Checking if the raycast (bullet) collided with objects tagged with "Enemy_Torso".
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy_Torso")) {
                    Debug.Log ("Body-shot!");
                    //hitPoint = hit.collider.gameObject;
                    enHit = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
                    enHit.enemyShotTorso();
                }
                // Checking if the raycast (bullet) collided with objects tagged with "Enemy_Limb".
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy_Limb")) {
                    Debug.Log ("Limb-shot!");
                    enHit = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
                    enHit.enemyShotLimb();
                }
                // The point of contact with the model is given by the hit.point (to not cause z-fighting issues with layering)
                Vector3 bulletHolePosition = hit.point + hit.normal * 0.01f;
                // Rotation to match where it hits (between the quad vector forward axis and the hit normal)
                Quaternion bulletHoleRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(-Vector3.forward, hit.normal);
                GameObject hole = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(bulletHolePrefab, bulletHolePosition, bulletHoleRotation);
                // Destroy the instantiated gameobject of the bulletHole after a delay of 5 seconds.
                Destroy (hole, 5.0f);
            }                                                                                                                    
        }
```

The following is my EnemyHealth script:

```
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour {

public float enemyHealth = 100.0f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    enemyDeath ();
}

public void enemyShotHead() {
    enemyHealth -= 60f;
    Debug.Log (enemyHealth);
}

public void enemyShotTorso() {
    enemyHealth -= 40f;
    Debug.Log (enemyHealth);
}

public void enemyShotLimb() {
    enemyHealth -= 20f;
    Debug.Log (enemyHealth);
}

void enemyDeath() {
    if (enemyHealth <= 0.0f) {
        Debug.Log ("Enemy Killed");
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

}

Any help with trying to figure out why it's not getting the reference / setting them would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The run time error occurs at line 107 in ShootGun.cs. Can you post the code on that line?

Comment: 107 is this line:
      enHit.enemyShotTorso();
under the Enemy_Torso check if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enHit is likely null. Repace all your

```
hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
```

with

```
hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
```

You have about 4 of them in your script. You want to get the EnemyHealth Script attached to the object the Ray hit through the collider.

**EDIT:**

You also need to change

```
hit.transform.CompareTag("Enemy_Head")
hit.transform.CompareTag("Enemy_Torso")
hit.transform.CompareTag("Enemy_Limb")
```

to

```
hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy_Head")
hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy_Torso")
hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy_Limb")
```

This may NOT solve the current error you are getting but it is one of the problems that is causing that error.

Comment: I've tried that, but I need to call a specific function on that script to deal the correct amount of damage (depending on the body part hit). enHint /should/ be set to hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>() it doesn't seem to detect it as a reference?

Comment: Replaced   enHit = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>(); 

with

 enHit =hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();

Then post the error you are having. Before you do that, edit your question and update your code with what I said.

Comment: Updated code.

Error :   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ShootGun.gunFire () (at Assets/Scripts/Gun/ShootGun.cs:113)

Line 113 = enHit.enemyShotTorso();

The error appears for each line where enHit tries to call a function from the enemyHealth script.

Comment: I updated my answer. That may not solve the problem but that is one of the problems you are having. Please update your code again and report back what happens. By the way, what is your Enemy Script attached to? What is your shootgun script attached to? Do you get any error about the camera on the line Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera> ().ViewportPointToRay (new Vector3 (0.5F, 0.5F, 0));?

Comment: Edited my code, the same error is still occurring. My EnemyHealth script is attached to each of my enemies, scattered across the map (I currently have 5). My ShootGun script is attached to the camera attached to my player character. I don't receive an error from the Ray ray = GetComponent... line

Comment: I am about to replicate what your doing here with cubes as torso, limbs... and see where the problem is. Can you give me more details about what you are trying to do with the current code you have. Do you have a gun in the scene and do you have a bullet that hits the enemy? What are you trying to do with 1 << 9 and 1 << 8?  

You should understand that the Enemy_Head, Enemy_Torso and Enemy_Limb must have the EnemyHealth  attached to them. Click on each part in the hierarchy and attach the script to each of them not your the parent object of your enemy.

Comment: If it's attached to each of them, will it not have  different health values? (one for each body part?)
EDIT: They do. Can I make it so they reference the parent gameobject for the health value instead? Also, I can link you to the github of the project if it's easier for you?
EDIT 2: 1 << 9 and 1 << 8 are layers. 8 is the environment, 9 are the enemies (so that it only detects collision with them)

Comment: Create another script called mainEnemyLife that contains the main enemy life. The main EnemyLife should contain a function that takes a float parameter. This mainEnemyLift script should be attached to the parent of the enemy gameobject while Enemy_Head, Enemy_Torso and Enemy_Limb must have the EnemyHealth attached to them. When there is a damage and the enemyHealth is called, you can then call the function in mainEnemyLife and pass it a float value on much life should be taken away. Post the project to github if you are still having problems.

Comment: Brilliant! The reference to the mainEnemyLife script works and I can have multiple enemies with independent health! Thank you so much, I really do appreciate it! You've been a great help. If I happen to have any other issues, is there a quick way that I can could contact you (I wouldn't bother you unless it deadly important). Thank you once again.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. I usually don't check my emails. I spend most of my time modeling and coding. The easiest way to contact me is to comment on any of my answers such as this one and I when I refresh my stackoverflow page, I will see the notification. So you can ask question on stackoverflow and comment on any of my answers to see if I can answer your question. You can then delete the comment afterwards when I see your new question. You can post your email and I will add you on my contact list. I will tell you to delete the email once I get it.

Comment: Okay great, I'll do the comment thing as it sounds the most convenient / unobtrusive way for you. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Unity also provides tutorials. I suggest you visit them and watch every scripting video they have. You will NOT learn everything in college and will have to figure out most of the stuff by your self or else you will end up having the same skills(lower skill) like others in your class. Here you go  http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules    . They also have live training where you can also ask questions while learning new stuff. Here is the link too http://unity3d.com/learn/live-training   . Good luck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245982/input-not-being-detected-yet-input-is-specified?noredirect=1#comment48593906_30245982 Once again, help man please?