# Input not being detected (yet input is specified)

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine

I have the following function to manage the reloading process of my player's gun in my game. I call the function from an AmmoCheck function and it runs, however the if statement is never run because the input doesn't get detected. The line:

*Debug.Log("Reload function check");*

will print to the console, but nothing further.

I have made sure the Input is set up under Edit>Project Settings>Input, and it is set to the r button. (**Proof** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMYeZ.png )

**The function:**

```
void gunReload()
{
    Debug.Log("Reload function check");
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Reload")) {

        Debug.Log("Reloading");
        if(changeWeapon.currentGun == changeWeapon.gunPistol) {
            aReload.SetActive(false);
            // Incrementing the aClipPistolCurrent value by 1 so the current clip "should" progress one along? idk
            aClipPistolCurrent += 1;
        }
        if(changeWeapon.currentGun == changeWeapon.gunAssault) {
            aReload.SetActive(false);
            // Incrementing the aClipPistolCurrent value by 1 so the current clip "should" progress one along? idk
            aClipAssaultCurrent += 1;
        }

    }       
}
```

**Function calling gunReload();**

gunAmmoCheck() is being called inside of Update()

```
void gunAmmoCheck()
{

    if(changeWeapon.currentGun == changeWeapon.gunPistol && aClipPistol[aClipPistolCurrent] > 0) {
        gunFire ();
        // Reducing the ammo of the current clip by 1.
        // ClipPistol is being used (say array, why array
        aClipPistol[aClipPistolCurrent] -= 1;
    }
    if(changeWeapon.currentGun == changeWeapon.gunAssault && aClipAssault[aClipAssaultCurrent] > 0) {
        gunFire ();
        // Reducing the ammo of the current clip by 1.
        // ClipPistol is being used (say array, why array
        aClipAssault[aClipAssaultCurrent] -= 1;
    }

    if(aClipPistol[aClipPistolCurrent] == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Reload");
        // Activating the reload notification on the interface
        aReload.SetActive(true);
        gunReload();
    }
    if(aClipAssault[aClipAssaultCurrent] == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Reload");
        // Activating the reload notification on the interface
        aReload.SetActive(true);
        noAmmo = true;
        gunReload();
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss here, since all of my other inputs work flawlessly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `GetKeyDown` work? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Comment: `GetKeyDown` works, but it only works for a single frame, the state is reset after the frame is complete so it has to be called in the `Update` method. Check the key state in the update routine and set a flag that is checked in the reload routine.

Comment: I'm sorry Ron, but could you explain it in a little more detail?

Comment: He hasn't said if this is not coming from `Update()` If we knew this was coming from a Coroutine, I would agree, but I'm pretty sure this is just a couple calls up the stack from `Update()`.

Comment: Sorry yes, the ammoCheck function that calls the reload function is called in Update().

Comment: Using GetKeyDown doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and it worked. I am starting to think that the problem is where you are calling the function from. Not sure yet but

Lets find the problem slowly. Can you comment out those things in your function and have only

```
 void gunReload ()
    {
        //Debug.Log ("Reload function check");
        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Reload")) {

            Debug.Log ("Reloading");

        }       
    }
```

in your code. Then call **gunReload ()** from the Update and tell me if it works. 
It would also be good to pose the function you are calling  **gunReload ()** from.

Comment: Doing what you've said logs the "Reloading" message so the input works for that. Update original question with the function I was calling it from originally.

Comment: One more thing. Can you post the line of code in the Update() where gunAmmoCheck() is called. For example, did you call it with gunAmmoCheck()  or did you have to check for some logic before you called it. For example, if(...){gunAmmoCheck()} ?

Comment: I currently have it under:

if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
   gunAmmoCheck();
  }

Which I now realise would probably mean I'd have to have Fire1 down at the same time as my reload button maybe?

Comment: Lol yes. that's the problem. Do you really want the player to be firing before they can reload? I haven't seen any game control like this before. Remove the gunAmmoCheck(); from that if statement and check if it is working properly now

Comment: /sigh. I'm an idiot, I swear. I must've looked through the script at least twenty times trying to figure out. What would you recommend I do fit in the Fire1 check as well as the reload check?

Comment: You are not. I make the same simple mistake too and that usually happens when you spend the whole day programming. If you take time off during times like this and then come back after, you'll likely be able to spot the problem right away. In the Fire check, check if bullet >0 then fire bullet, play the shoot sound, decrement bullet amount. But If bullet ==0, you can play the empty shoot gun sound that lets the player know that the gun is empty, call reload automatically if user enabled the automatic reload and maybe show a little gui symbol that shows that the gun is empty or out of bullets.

Comment: Well it definitely feels like it sometimes. I really appreciate the help you've given me though man, thank you very much!