# Unity 4.6 Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Component' to `DamageInterface'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having an issue trying to get my game to compile, the issue stems from my damage interface script and my projectile script. The error code in the console is as follows.

*Assets/Scripts/Projectile.cs(32,33): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Component' to`DamageInterface'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

**DamageInterface.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
//damage interface

public interface DamageInterface {

    void TakeHit (float damage, RaycastHit hit);

}
```

**Projectile.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {

    public LayerMask collisionMask; //detect what layer projectile collides with 
    float speed = 10;
    float damage = 1;

    public void SetSpeed(float newSpeed) {
        speed = newSpeed;
    }

    void Update () {
        float moveDistance = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        CheckCollisions (moveDistance);
        transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * moveDistance);
    }


    void CheckCollisions(float moveDistance) { //raycast to detect collision
        Ray ray = new Ray (transform.position, transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, moveDistance, collisionMask)) {
            OnHitObject(hit);
        }
    }


    void OnHitObject(RaycastHit hit) {
        DamageInterface damageableObject = hit.collider.GetComponent(typeof(DamageInterface)); //ERROR RESIDES HERE
        if (damageableObject != null) {
            damageableObject.TakeHit(damage, hit); //damage + raycast hit
        }
        GameObject.Destroy (gameObject); //destroy projectile if enemy layer is hit
    } 
}
```

I believe I have used the typeof(T) approach to get my interface component but I must be missing something clearly. Thanks

The error resides on this line in my Projectile.cs:

```
DamageInterface damageableObject = hit.collider.GetComponent(typeof(DamageInterface));
```

Comment: include code for RaycastHit in other words does it implement DamageInterface or well the collider object

Comment: How would that look I don't believe I have done that as I have had to alter my code after moving from unity 5 to unity 4

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020429/raycast-to-get-gameobject-being-hit-to-run-script-and-function-on-gameobject

Comment: DamageInterface does not extend Behaviour, or Component.

Comment: That's similar to how I originally had it when it was compiling in unity 5, previous versions do not fetch interfaces with that function which is where my issue is residing

Comment: Just tried extending them and receive a parsing error

Comment: Have you tried `GetComponent<DamageInterface>()`? It should return you a DamangeInterface instead of a Component

Comment: DamageInterface damageableObject = hit.collider.GetComponent<DamageInterface>(); I believe only works in unity 5+, get parsing error when trying that

Answer (score 3):

In Unity5.x you can fetch component that are interfaces like this:

```
IInterface myInterface = gameObject.GetComponent<IInterface>();
```

in older version you need to perform a cast:

```
 IInterface myInterface = (IInterface)gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(IInterface));
```

this is because GetComponent returns a Component and your interface is not. The error actually tells you what to do:

*An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Yes you were missing the cast.

Comment: Thanks seems relatively straight forward now. I'll implement it when I get home and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: And you cannot use the generic version with interface in old Unity.

Comment: hi @Ben411916 it's important and helpful to TICK any useful answer, to help close out questions. there is an incredible amount of clutter in this tag on SO and it's becoming hard to get questions answered.  cheers

Comment: @Everts hey do you know how you could convert this "IInterface myInterface = gameObject.GetComponent<IInterface>();" into a bool for an if statement, to say if gameobject.getcomponent<IInterface>() return true

Comment: You could something like the following : public static bool IsComponentAvailable<T>(this GameObject obj, ref T t){ t = obj.GetComponent<T>(); return t != null;} then you use as if(gameObject.IsComponentAvailable<IInterface>(ref interfaceRef) == true){}